# Is structure group order considered when resolving links with proximity?

Tags: dynamic-linking

In the [description of the proximity algorithm in the documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-F9F52365-2ABE-4C1E-A50C-3D4CA4F84989), the logic is described in terms of "a Web page in a .... Web folder", but no mention seems to be made of the order of the "Web folders".

I had long assumed that the order was also relevant, but I have recently observed that the resolved link doesn't always come out at the "closest" page in that sense.

Does the algorithm ignore the ordering, and if so, what is the result based on? Is it perhaps simply the first matching record found by a database query?

What would be the best way to ensure links would resolve to the closest match taking order into account?

Comment: Maybe page creation date is used (most recently created), since this is used as fallback for CT priority and proximity.

Answer (score 3):

By the page itself, the page that link resolves is the Page first created. Documentation states so:

> **Resolving a link using Page creation date**
>
> It is conceivable that the most preferred location for the link target
> contains two Web pages that each contain a Component Presentation that
> render the target Component using Component Templates of the same
> priority. In this case, the link still cannot be resolved, neither
> through priority nor through location. In this case, the link will
> point to the Web page whose corresponding Page in Content Manager was
> most recently created (regardless of which Web page was published
> first).

So what I think is the case, when multiple structure groups on same level have pages with CP, **all of them are retrieved from DB and the one first created will be resolved.**